# Simple XML Serialization with Retrofit2 with Multiple In-Line Items

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

Using Retrofit2 with SimpleXmlConverterFactory

My issue is multiple in-line (I believe?) Errors in the error response's errorBody.

I have been referring to [this link from Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline) as my source of information.

I am working with the below response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Info>This is why</Info>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Code>2</Code>
        <Info>This is why</Info>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

My current java objects are ErrorResponse.java:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

import java.util.List;

@Root(name="Errors")
public class ErrorResponse {

    @ElementList(name="Error", inline = true)
    List<Error> errors;

    public ErrorResponse() {
        // no arg constructor
    }

    public void setErrors(List<Error> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<Error> getErrors() {
        return this.errors;
    }
}
```

and Error.java:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class Error {

    @Element(name="Code")
    int code;

    @Element(name="Info")
    String info;

    public Error() {
        // no arg constructor
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }
}
```

The error I get when trying to parse the errorBody of the response is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: 
Element 'Error' does not have a match in class com.my.package.ErrorResponse at line 1
```

If there's only 1 error item and I change the ErrorResponse class to:

```
..
@Root
public class ErrorResponse {

    @Element(name="Error")
    Error error;
...
...
```

Then everything works fine and dandy.  The issue comes when there are multiple Errors.  Any help or suggestions getting this XML to be parsed properly would be great.  I use the below code for the errorBody parsing of the response:

```
Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> converter = mRetrofit.responseBodyConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
try {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The closing info,`</Info>`, tag needs to be capitalized in your sample XML
- `ErrorResponse` needs a name of `Errors` to match the XML
- `@ElementList` doesn't need the name specified when it's `inline`
- `ErrorItem` needs `@Root(name = "Error")`

Here is the code for `ErrorResponse`:

```
@Root(name = "Errors")
public class ErrorResponse {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    List<Error> errors;

    public ErrorResponse() {
        // no arg constructor
    }

    public void setErrors(List<Error> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<Error> getErrors() {
        return this.errors;
    }
}
```

For `Error`:

```
@Root(name = "Error")
public class Error {

    @Element(name = "Code")
    int code;

    @Element(name = "Info")
    String info;

    public Error() {
        // no arg constructor
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }
}
```

Fixed sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Info>This is why</Info>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <Code>2</Code>
        <Info>This is why</Info>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Comment: Thank you so much James!